# How to share without links/images/media with iOS Facebook SDK?

Tags: sharing, fbsdk

I've gone through the [Facebook Sharing Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios), and there's one simple thing I can't seem to do (without the built-in dialog): how do I simply share a status text?

I've tried the following code after some StackOverflow browsing:

```
FBSDKShareAPI * shareApi = [[FBSDKShareAPI alloc]init];
shareApi.message = self.fbMessage.text;
shareApi.delegate = self;
[shareApi share];
```

However, that fails with FB SDK Error 2 "Share content cannot be null". Seems like I am obligated to fill in the shareApi.content property with one of the content objects: link/photo/video/multimedia. But I really don't want to attach any of these...

How do I simply post a status text message?

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a solution using FBSDKGraphRequest:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"message": self.fbMessage.text};
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                              parameters:params
                              HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:nil];
```